# Connect to Microsoft Graph via Access Token

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to connect to the Microsoft Graph API without user intervention, and am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) guide on how to do so. I am able to get past step 4, where I receive my access token. However, I continue to receive an error saying that my access token is empty.

The first part of my code successfully gets the access token:

```html
import urllib3

uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/companyID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

payload= {

    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'

        }

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('POST', uri, payload)

print(response.data)

my_dict = eval(response.data)
token = f"{my_dict['token_type']} {my_dict['access_token']}"
```

When I try running this second part to connect to the Graph API:

```html
import urllib3
uri2 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/12345678-73a6-4952-a53a-e9916737ff7f'

payload2 = {
    'Authorization':token,
    'Host':'graph.microsoft.com'
        }

https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response2 = http.request ('GET', uri2, payload2)
print(response2.data)
```

I get this error:

```html
b'{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-21T13:55:42","request-id":"xxxxxxxxx-aced-469c-a68c-xxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxx-aced-469c-a68c-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}'
```

All of the permissions are correctly set up on the app's end, I'm scratching my head on why the token is saying it's empty. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
response2 = http.request ('GET', uri2, payload2)
```

to

```
response2 = http.request ('GET', uri2, headers=payload2)
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and granted **permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I ran the **same code** as you and got the **`token`** successfully as below:

```py
import urllib3
uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload= {

    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
 }
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', uri, payload)
print(response.data)
my_dict = eval(response.data)
token = f"{my_dict['token_type']} {my_dict['access_token']}"
```

**Output:**

[image]

When I tried to call Graph API with **same code**, I got **same error** as you like below:

```py
import urllib3
uri2 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/d6076090-fxx9-4xxa-8xxf-4xxxxxxxxx3'
payload2 = {
    'Authorization':token,
    'Host':'graph.microsoft.com'
        }
https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response2 = http.request ('GET', uri2, payload2)
print(response2.data)
```

**Output:**

[image]

As you included **`Authorization`** in parameters instead of **headers**, your code is unable to identify the token.

To **resolve** the error, try to modify your code like below:

```py
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
uri2 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/d6076090-fxx9-4xxa-8xxf-4xxxxxxxxx3'
response2 = http.request ('GET', uri2, headers={    
        "Authorization": token
})
print(response2.data)
```

**Output:**

[image]

I got the user's details in the **response** successfully when I used the modified code.